# Building angular app with dynamic environment using startup.sh file in docker container

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, gcloud

So i'm using gcloud run to deploy my docker containers with my angular app.
This is my file structure:

[image]

Inside of my docker folder there is a startup.sh file which i want to run.

My dockerfile looks like this:

```
# Stage 0, "build-stage", based on Node.js, to build and compile the frontend
FROM tiangolo/node-frontend:10 as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY ./ /app/

RUN npm run build -- --output-path=./dist/out
# Stage 1, based on Nginx, to have only the compiled app, ready for production with Nginx
FROM nginx:1.15

COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist/out/ /usr/share/nginx/html
# Copy the default nginx.conf provided by tiangolo/node-frontend
COPY --from=build-stage /nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY ../docker /app/
WORKDIR /app/docker
RUN /startup.sh
```

When gcloud runs my dockerfile i always get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: /startup.sh: not found
```

So I guess my copy of the docker folder is not working out as I think it does or maybe i'm not in the right folder. I'm very new to docker so there might be something really basic that i've missed here.

Comment: Where is startup.sh? How are you building the Docker image?

Comment: startup.sh is located in the docker folder at the root of the project

Comment: i dont know what you mean by building the docker image? :/ Isn't gcloud building it using my dockerfile?

Comment: This is sort of the print debugging of Dockerfiles, but if you build the Docker image and override the entry point, you can take a look at exactly where everything is being copied to.

Comment: Nothing is in your image unless you explicitly `COPY` it there.  You can usually `docker run --rm -it your-image-name sh` to get a debugging shell on a built image to look around and see what's actually there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding absolute paths.

Make sure that you have bash installed within your container.

Add the permission to execute the file.

Try to run this bash script with a `CMD`.

```
COPY /docker /app/
RUN apk add --no-cache bash
RUN chmod +x /app/docker/startup.sh
# RUN /app/docker/startup.sh
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/app/docker/startup.sh"]
```